# Obfuscate Assembly containing DataBindings to internal class properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, internal, dotfuscator

I have a UserControl with a ViewModel class as DataContext:

XAML

```
<UserControl ... >    
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelProperty}"/>
</UserControl>
```

CodeBehind:

```
namespace DotfuscatorTest.UserControl.View
{
   using ViewModel;
   public partial class UserControlView
   {
      public UserControlView()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         DataContext = new UserControlViewModel();         
      }
   }
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
namespace DotfuscatorTest.UserControl.ViewModel
{
   internal class UserControlViewModel
   {
      private string viewModelProperty = "hello world";

      public string ViewModelProperty
      {
        get { return viewModelProperty; }
        set { viewModelProperty = value; }
      }
   }
}
```

This example runs fine (data binding works correctly). But now, when I obfuscate this assembly with Dotfuscator (Version 4.9.7750) the binding doesn't work. If I make the UserControlViewModel class public the application runs fine also after obfuscating.

As I understand, Dotfuscator doesn't change the name of the property when it is public, but changes it if its private or internal class.

My question now is, how do you handle this problem. I think it's common have internal classes with properties which are used in DataBindings, isn't it?
Or is there a way to configure Dotfuscator?

Thanks in advance,
rhe1980

Answer (score 2):

By default, Dotfuscator performs property name obfuscation (renaming), which inherently breaks XAML bindings.  It will attempt to correct for this by also renaming the binding target in the XAML, but isn't always successful, as in this situation.  The easiest way to correct this without changing your code is to add a renaming exclusion in Dotfuscator.  You should be able to look in the "Rename" tab and exclude the ViewModel in question from renaming.